# Display a georeferenced DEM surface in 3D matplotlib

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, numpy, matplotlib

I want to use a DEM file to generate a simulated terrain surface using matplotlib.  But I do not know how to georeference the raster coordinates to a given CRS.  Nor do I know how to express the georeferenced raster in a format suitable for use in a 3D matplotlib plot, for example as a numpy array.

Here is my python code so far:

```
import osgeo.gdal
dataset = osgeo.gdal.Open("MergedDEM")
gt = dataset.GetGeoTransform()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Matplotlib knows nothing about georeferenced surfaces, it only knows x,y,z coordinates. You can also use [Visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/) or [Mayavi](http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/).

- the original DEM

[image]

- you must first extract the x,y, z coordinates of the grid ( a raster is a grid of pixels and with a DEM, the value of the pixel is the elevation, z) with osgeo.gdal. No script here because  it is possible to find the solutions on Gis StackExchange or on the web.
- after, you can plot the points in 3D

  ```
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import *
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib import cm
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = Axes3D(fig)
  ax.scatter3D(x,y,z,c=z,cmap=plt.cm.jet)  
  plt.show()
  ```

[image]

- and you must reconstruct a 3D grid (surface) with the function griddata of matplotlib (Delaunay)

  ```
  import numpy as np
  from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
  # craation of a 2D grid
  xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
  yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))
  X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
  # interpolation
  Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = Axes3D(fig)
  ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,linewidth=1, antialiased=True)
  plt.show()
  ```

The grid (with visvis):

[image]!

The coloured grid (with matplotlib):

[image]

- but you can also use others interpolation algorithms (Scipy thin-plate spline here) and drape colours

  ```
  import scipy as sp
  import scipy.interpolate
  # 2D grid construction
  spline = sp.interpolate.Rbf(x,y,z,function='thin-plate')
  xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
  yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))
  X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
  # interpolation
  Z = spline(X,Y)
  ```

[image]

With [Visvis](http://code.google.com/p/visvis/), you can make animations:

[image]

You can even plot the 3D contours:

[image]

- Comparison between a projected DEM (with GRASS GIS, x 1) and the equivalent non projected DEM (x,y,z, with Visvis x 1)

[image] [image]

Comment: I am new in matplotlib, I converted my raster file to csv file in x y z format. How can I use my csv file in first your code?