# What is meaning of scale on x and y axis of image using matplotlib

Tags: elevation, terrain, matplotlib

I am finding elevation of a region using richdem.

Can somebody tell me what is the meaning of the scale which is on the x and y axis of the image?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import elevation
import richdem as rd
dem_path = "C:\\Users\\ARSH\\Desktop\\semester 8\\n12_e079_1arc_v3.tif"

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 5.5)
shasta_dem = rd.LoadGDAL(dem_path)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
plt.imshow(shasta_dem, interpolation='none',cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: this the the output of the above code.]

Comment: Could it be the DEM coordinates, for example in meters?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, [richdem](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) use [osgeo.gdal](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/) to open the raster and the result is a numpy array with the elevations values.

```
shasta_dem = rd.LoadGDAL('mydem.tiff')
shasta_dem.shape
(60, 100)
print(shasta_dem)
[[170.52 170.74 170.81 ... 195.55 195.72 195.93]
[169.09 169.09 168.69 ... 196.58 196.61 196.73]
[166.79 166.75 165.95 ... 197.   197.29 197.66]
...
[191.41 191.85 192.57 ... 194.74 194.69 194.13]
[186.95 186.49 187.27 ... 195.88 195.9  195.86]
[184.65 184.   184.44 ... 196.99 197.02 197.02]]
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 8))
plt.imshow(shasta_dem, interpolation='none',cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

[image]

x and y are simply the shape of the array (60 lines and 100 columns in my example) because Matplotlib knows nothing about georeferenced rasters ( (look at [Display a georeferenced DEM surface in 3D matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66440)).

> The typical geospatial coordinate reference system is defined on a cartesian plane with the 0,0 origin in the bottom left and X and Y increasing as you go up and to the right. But raster data, coming from its image processing origins, uses a different referencing system to access pixels. We refer to rows and columns with the 0,0 origin in the upper left and rows increase and you move down while the columns increase as you go right (from [Python affine transforms](http://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html))

A solution is to take into account the [Geotransform matrix](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#geotransform)

```
gt = shasta_dem.geotransform
```

But [richdem](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) does not allow to get the dimensions of the dem ([def LoadGDAL(filename, no_data=None) in init.py](https://github.com/r-barnes/richdem/blob/82baaa2bf857ee0b9d2d2ddabe43655eb711d110/wrappers/pyrichdem/richdem/__init__.py)) to compute the real extension of the dem for matplotlib

Therefore, with GDAL

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open(dem)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
extent = (gt[0], gt[0] + ds.RasterXSize * gt[1],gt[3] + ds.RasterYSize * gt[5], gt[3])
print(extent)
(202086.57700025057, 205625.41440703123, 88411.04799999669, 90534.35044407193) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
img = ax.imshow(data, extent=extent, origin='upper', cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

[image]